# How to cat multiple lines with indentation in bash function?

Tags: bash, function, echo, here-document

I have a bash function

```
yumtelegraf() {
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/influxdb.repo
[influxdb]
name = InfluxDB Repository - RHEL \$releasever
baseurl = https://repos.influxdata.com/rhel/\$releasever/\$basearch/stable
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key
EOF
sudo yum install telegraf
}
```

If I use indentation in function it is printing tab spaces to file...

```
yumtelegraf() {
  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/influxdb.repo
  [influxdb]
  name = InfluxDB Repository - RHEL \$releasever
  baseurl = 
  https://repos.influxdata.com/rhel/\$releasever/\$basearch/stable
  enabled = 1
  gpgcheck = 1
  gpgkey = https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key
  EOF
  sudo yum install telegraf
}
```

How to avoid this behavior?
Is this possible with echo command also?

Comment: if you use `<<-EOF` (note the `-` before `EOF`), then bash will ignore leading tab characters in the heredoc.  It doesn't do the same for leading spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Either use tabs and `<<-EOF` (with the dash) or use a filter instead of cat, eg. `sed`:

```
$ sed -e "s/^\s*//" <<EOF
 as
  df
   gh
    jk
        op    # two tabs
EOF
```

This removes both spaces and tabs. Note that the closing `EOF` cannot be indented. You might use `<<"  EOF"` and then the again `"  EOF"` with the same number of spaces as the end token, but the quotes block the expansions in the here-document, which you don't want in this case. Compare:

```
$ a=x
$ cat <<EOF
"$a"
EOF
"x"
$ cat <<"EOF"
"$a"
EOF
"$a"
```

As for `echo` it has problems with this. But you can use `printf` also:

```
printf "%s\n" \
  "[influxdb]" \
  "name = InfluxDB Repository - RHEL \$releasever" \
  "baseurl = https://repos.influxdata.com/rhel/\$releasever/\$basearch/stable" \
  "enabled = 1" \
  "gpgcheck = 1" \
  "gpgkey = https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key" \
| sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/influxdb.repo
```

I left the dashes in `\$` as in your question, but they may not be correct here, as they're escaping the expansions.

Comment: yes... but this trims all leading and trailing spaces. I want to know if there is any way to not disturb the echo command when using indentation.

Comment: @AkhilJ No, `^\s*` matches only from the line start.

Comment: @AkhilJ Also see my update about `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<<-` (note the `-`) which specifically enables what you want.

```bsh
yumtelegraf() {
  cat <<-EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/influxdb.repo
  [influxdb]
  name = InfluxDB Repository - RHEL \$releasever
  baseurl = 
  https://repos.influxdata.com/rhel/\$releasever/\$basearch/stable
  enabled = 1
  gpgcheck = 1
  gpgkey = https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key
  EOF
  sudo yum install telegraf
}
```

Comment: this is now working for me. getting this `bash: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted \`EOF')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `echo -e "\tblabla"`:

```
$ echo -e "\tblabla\n\t\tblibli\n\t\t\tbloblo\n"
    blabla
        blibli
            bloblo
```

As explained in bash manual page:

```
If the -e option is given, interpretation of the following backslash-escaped characters is enabled.
[...]
              \a     alert (bell)
              \b     backspace
              \c     suppress further output
              \e
              \E     an escape character
              \f     form feed
              \n     new line
              \r     carriage return
              \t     horizontal tab
              \v     vertical tab
              \\     backslash
              \0nnn  the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (zero to three octal digits)
              \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
              \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
              \UHHHHHHHH
                     the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
```